# How a more than 256bytes Look Up table can be accessed using neon?

Tags: arm, simd, neon

I need to access a 256 valued look up table of integer type using neon.
Is there any possibility to access like that?

If indexes in my vector in sequential manner i will do, or upto 256 bits i will do with VTBL.
Here my index vector indexes any of 0 - 255 range. so, I am unable to do it.

If anyone knows about this
please help me.

Regards,
Smily

Answer (score 2):

Look at the VTBX instruction, it can be used to extend a NEON table look up. For example:

```
// indices in d30, result to d31

VMOV.8 d29, #16
VTBL.8 d31, {q0, q1}, d30
VSUB.8 d30, d30, d29
VTBX.8 d31, {q2, q3}, d30
VSUB.8 d30, d30, d29
VTBX.8 d31, {q4, q5}, d30
```

However, a 256 byte table will require the entire NEON register file, so you will have to reload (parts of) your table for each vector look up.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible with NEON.

You should think why you are using LUTs in first place. Most of the time, LUTs are used to save cycles doing complex math, but NEON is so powerful that it can handle that kind of maths with ease.

Brute force arithmetic is the name of the game with NEON. You should look at how the LUT gets generated to start with and do the math with NEON on-the-fly.